# Anaconda jupyter notebook will not start on Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am suddenly having a problem starting jupyter notebook on my Mac, OS X Sierra 10.12.6. I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda 4.2.0, check anaconda.com. Here is what happens:

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 17:00:20.982 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 3 kernels found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 652, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1071, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 919, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 194, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/Users/myUserName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

I can't find help.

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything running on the port. You can check it with `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`

Comment: I had been trying to work with a headless Raspberry Pi over USB. The RPi "acted like Ethernet", whatever that means. I had a lot of zombie TCP connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem opening your port, maybe another app is using the port or something is blocking jupyter. Maybe you can try other port using a command like this:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8081
```

Comment: Ok. This worked! I don't understand how jupyter chooses a port. It must be a software port. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to here that, you can check what program is using your port with '''$ lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN'''. Could mark the question as answered?.

Comment: This worked, but I would have never figured it out. I googled all kinds of variations of _jupyter notebook not starting_.